# POI writes corrupted .xlsx when adding large number of ValidationData in a sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to write a large `.xlsx` file(50K rows) using POI in JAVA. I expect each row to contain multiple drop-down cells. The code works fine when the number of rows is less than 30K but writes a corrupt file if the number of rows exceeds 35K.

I have tried `SXSSFWorkbook` and `XSSFWorkbook` but none worked for me.

Here is the code:

```
        SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
        SXSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
        String[] optionsArray = new String[] {"1000.00","2000.00"};
        int no_of_rows = 35000;
        for(int i=0;i<=no_of_rows;i++) {
            SXSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow(i);
            SXSSFCell r1c1 = row1.createCell(0);
            DataValidationConstraint  constraint1 = sheet.getDataValidationHelper().createExplicitListConstraint(optionsArray);
            CellRangeAddressList addressList1 = new CellRangeAddressList(i, i, 0, 0);
            DataValidation dataValidation1 = sheet.getDataValidationHelper().createValidation(constraint1, addressList1);
            sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation1);
            r1c1.setCellValue("1000.00");   

            SXSSFCell r1c2 = row1.createCell(1);
            DataValidationConstraint  constraint2 = sheet.getDataValidationHelper().createExplicitListConstraint(optionsArray);
            CellRangeAddressList addressList2 = new CellRangeAddressList(i, i, 1, 1);
            DataValidation dataValidation2 = sheet.getDataValidationHelper().createValidation(constraint2, addressList2);
            sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation2);
            r1c2.setCellValue("2000.00");
        }
        FileOutputStream fos =new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\data\\testout.xlsx"));
        workbook.write(fos);
        workbook.close();
        fos.close();
```

I expect POI to work well with 50K rows of such data at least.

Comment: I would guess that there is a limit on the number of `DataValidations` that can be contained in one workbook. As of now you create 70002 different data validations

Comment: Right! Works fine with less than 65500 data validations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not creating a `DataValidation` for each single cell. Instead do only creating the two needed data validations, one for `A1:A50001` and the second for `B1:B50001`. To do so the `CellRangeAddressList`s can contain the whole column ranges:

```
CellRangeAddressList addressList1 = new CellRangeAddressList(0, no_of_rows, 0, 0);
```

and

```
CellRangeAddressList addressList1 = new CellRangeAddressList(0, no_of_rows, 1, 1);
```

Your example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.*;

class CreateSXSSFWorkbookDataValidations {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
        SXSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

        String[] optionsArray = new String[] {"1000.00","2000.00"};

        int no_of_rows = 50000;

        for(int i=0;i<=no_of_rows;i++) {
            SXSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow(i);
            SXSSFCell r1c1 = row1.createCell(0);
            r1c1.setCellValue("1000.00");   
            SXSSFCell r1c2 = row1.createCell(1);
            r1c2.setCellValue("2000.00");
        }

        DataValidationConstraint constraint1 = sheet.getDataValidationHelper().createExplicitListConstraint(optionsArray);
        CellRangeAddressList addressList1 = new CellRangeAddressList(0, no_of_rows, 0, 0);
        DataValidation dataValidation1 = sheet.getDataValidationHelper().createValidation(constraint1, addressList1);
        sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation1);

        DataValidationConstraint constraint2 = sheet.getDataValidationHelper().createExplicitListConstraint(optionsArray);
        CellRangeAddressList addressList2 = new CellRangeAddressList(0, no_of_rows, 1, 1);
        DataValidation dataValidation2 = sheet.getDataValidationHelper().createValidation(constraint2, addressList2);
        sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation2);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("testout.xlsx"));
        workbook.write(fos);
        workbook.close();
        fos.close();


    }
}
```

Having different unique data validation for each singe cell is not possible when the count of different unique data validations exceeds a limit. This limitation is an `Excel` limitation, not an `apache poi` one.

This special limit for data validations is not documented in [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3). But it might have to do with the limitations of unique cell formats/cell styles (64,000) or with the limitation of hyperlinks in a worksheet (66,530).

Comment: My requirement is to show a different dropdown list for each cell, hence using different constraint for each cell.

Comment: @Rahul Saxena: This is not possible because of `Excel` limitations when the count of different unique data validations exceeds a limit. See my supplement in the answer.

Comment: Right! This should be MS excel limitation.
As this limitation exists per sheet, I guess I have to split my data and write multiple sheets based on number of validations that can be added per sheet.
Thanks for sharing your thoughts on this.